# Invertibility of an $n$ by $n$ binary matrix in which each column has exactly $b$ ones

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, binary

In my research an important part has boiled down to the following linear algebra puzzle. For which $n, b \in \mathbb{R}$ can we construct a binary matrix $A$ such that $A$ is invertible and each column of $A$ has exactly $b$ ones in it. I would like to know if this holds for general $b \in (2, \dots, n -1)$.

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: I went down the route of circulant matrices and found a paper in which if the GCD of b and n is 1 then the circulant matrix defined by $e_1 + \dots + e_b$  is invertible. However this is much too strong of an assumption.